# Gitlab runner artifacts : 405 Method Not allowed

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I try to use artifacts on my Gitlab and when my runner try to put my artifact file on Giltlab, i have this message :

```
WARNING: Uploading artifacts to coordinator... failed  id=504 responseStatus=405 Method Not Allowed status=405 Method Not Allowed token=HebbSqMD
WARNING: Retrying...                               
WARNING: Uploading artifacts to coordinator... failed  id=504 responseStatus=405 Method Not Allowed status=405 Method Not Allowed token=HebbSqMD
WARNING: Retrying...                               
WARNING: Uploading artifacts to coordinator... failed  id=504 responseStatus=405 Method Not Allowed status=405 Method Not Allowed token=HebbSqMD
FATAL: invalid argument                            
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

My job is :

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Building the app" > out.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - out.txt
```

Gitlab 8.16 or 8.17 : same probleme

Gitlab runner on other host (docker executor) : 1.11.0 o 1.10.4 : same probleme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, verified artifacts enabled in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file:

```
    ## Build Artifacts
    # gitlab_rails['artifacts_enabled'] = true
    # gitlab_rails['artifacts_path'] = "/mnt/storage/artifacts"
```

Comment: Does it mean that you have to set this in _GitLab_ administration? Not in _GitLab Runner_ side?